# Tween color as item ages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What is the best way to tween a color as something gets older? I want to be persistant so I'm using a difference in time determine the age, not just running an animation after something happens.

The goal is a smooth even transition between two colors over something like 10 min that maintains state on reloads.

Thanks

EDIT: I will have a time sent from the server, I will use that, and current time, to get an elapsed time value. I then want to figure out how far along this is on a dynamic scale (meaning it could be 10min, could be 30min). After that I want to assign the correct color and have it continue aging.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to pick up this animation in the middle, and smoothly fade through every possible color along the way (not chunk it out step by step).

Comment: The tweening part is easy; you just do simple linear interpolation in the 3-dimensional color coordinate space. But it's not clear what you want; do you want the initial color on page load to reflect the age, and then have the age continue to change slowly?

Comment: could you give some more details? you tagged the question as javascript ... try posting the html

Comment: Unless you use some HTML5 local storage features, you will need some server-side component in order to maintain the colors on reload.

Comment: @mwcz yep I'm handling that server-side. @Pointy Sorry, I will update with more detail.

Comment: @mwcz, you forgot good old cookies rather quickly.

Comment: Which are you asking about?

* How to interpolate a color
* How to keep updating something on the page over a long-ish period of time
* How to change time info into an interpolation variable

Comment: @davin Good point, although I question the first adjective. :)

Comment: @mwcz, what's wrong with cookies? If you didn't have them, how would you handle server-side state?

Comment: @davin Lots of things, mostly related to the fact that you can never really trust a cookie.  You are right, though, they slipped my mind and would be fine for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jqueryui the tweening is pretty simple without the persistence.  Something like this should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/MeqVZ/

Change 6000 to 600000 if you want it to change over ten minutes (time is in milliseconds).

Putting persistence in will depend on how you want to keep persistence.  Are you saving the data to a database, do you want to set a cookie, do you want to use web/dom storage?

You would have to get the time left (dependent on how you want to store the time), on reload of a page calculate the current color (e.g., if you are fading from some color from 0 (#00) to 255 (#FF), and have spent 284 seconds of 600 seconds (10 minutes), you'd need to set the color to 255*284/600.0 like

```
color_init = parseInt("00", 16);
color_final = parseInt("FF", 16);
yourNum = Math.ceil((color_init-color_final)*284/600.0);
initial_color = yourNum.toString(16);
```

except you'd have to this for the red, green and blue parts of your color.

Use that in the initial color on the page (and have it as an animation with 600-284 seconds left).

EDIT: Updated fiddle.  To automatically start animating; and allow to start midway through (assuming you can read the value from the server).